# Avoid Controllers initialization when testing spring boot HandlerInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to find the right configuration for testing `HandlerInterceptor` of a Spring-boot application, with `@MockBean` dependencies, but without initializing the whole Bean pool, because some Controllers have `@PostConstruct` calls that can't be mocked (knowing that `@Before` call comes after `@PostContruct` Controller call).

For now I have come to this syntax :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class MyHandlerInterceptorTest {
  @Autowired
  private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;
  @Autowired
  private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;
  @MockBean
  private ProprieteService proprieteService;
  @MockBean
  private AuthentificationToken authentificationToken;

  @Before
  public void initMocks(){
    given(proprieteService.methodMock(anyString())).willReturn("foo");
  }

  @Test
  public void testInterceptorOptionRequest() throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    request.setRequestURI("/some/path");
    request.setMethod("OPTIONS");

    MockHttpServletResponse response = processPreHandleInterceptors(request);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatus());
  }
}
```

But test fails, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` because one `RestController` having a @PostContruct call tries to get data from `proprieteService` mock who have not been mocked at this moment.

So my question is : how can I prevent Springboot test loader to initialize all my Controllers, which 1: I don't need for the test, 2: Trigger calls that happen before I can mock anything ?

Comment: Write a unit test NOT an integration test. Just instantiate the `HandlerInterceptor`, create mocks and inject them.

Comment: In that case, how to mock `@autowired` dependencies in my Interceptor  ? I would need special Spring boot annotations, `@SpringBootTest` was doing the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@M. Deinum showed me the way, indeed the solution was to write a real Unit test. My concern was that I needed to populate those `@autowired` dependencies in my `Intercepter`, and was searching for some magic annotation. But it was simpler to just edit the custom `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and pass the dependencies via constructor like this :

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  AuthentificationToken authentificationToken;

  @Autowired
  public CustomWebMvcConfigurerAdapter(AuthentificationToken authentificationToken) {
    this.authentificationToken = authentificationToken;
  }

  @Bean
  public CustomHandlerInterceptor customHandlerInterceptor() {
    return new CustomHandlerInterceptor(authentificationToken);
  }

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(customHandlerInterceptor());
  }
}
```

And interceptor :

```
public class CustomHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
  private AuthentificationToken authentificationToken;

  @Autowired
  public CustomHandlerInterceptor(AuthentificationToken authentificationToken) {
    this.authentificationToken = authentificationToken;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
  }
}
```

Hope this can help.